# Create tests for parser combinators II in Scala

Tags: scala, testing, parser-combinators

Consider [this](https://github.com/wonook/2015_Fall_FoundationsOfSoftware/blob/master/1-arithmetic/src/main/scala/fos/Arithmetic.scala) source code that implements a parser for a term language in Scala. The main function, designed to test its functionality is defined as:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val stdin = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in))
    val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(stdin.readLine())
    phrase(term)(tokens) match {
      case Success(trees, _) =>
        for (t <- path(trees))
          println(t)
        try {
          print("Big step: ")
          println(eval(trees))
        } catch {
          case TermIsStuck(t) => println("Stuck term: " + t)
        }
      case e =>
        println(e)
    }
  }
```

I wrote the following test:

```
package fos

import org.scalatest.FunSuite


class ArithmeticTest extends FunSuite {

  test("testTerm") {

    Arithmetic.term(new Arithmetic.lexical.Scanner("if iszero pred pred 2 then if iszero 0 then true else false else false")) match {
      case Success(res,next) => assert(res == If(IsZero(Pred(Pred(Succ(Succ(Zero))))),If(IsZero(Zero),True,False),False))
      case Failure(msg,next) => assert(false)
    }
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, the Success and Failure cases are not recognized even if I mix-in `StandardTokenParsers` like in the link above. How can I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Arithmetic.Success` and `Arithmetic.Failure`, just like you have `Arithmetic.lexical.Scanner`. Alternatively, you could `import Arithmetic._`.